# C# class library, access object properties

Tags: c#, class-library

I have a function which suppose to receive an object as parameter and use its properties for further use,but when i try to access object properties it mark them as red (can't resolve symbol...)
 i tried to add few references but it didn't help.

[image]

```
public bool InsertStudent(object student)
{
    var db = DAL.Services.SqlServicesPool.HackService;
    using (var connection = db.StartConnection())
    {
        var sqlParam = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@Name", student.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Lname", student.Lname),
            new SqlParameter("@Phone", student.Phone),
            new SqlParameter("@Email", student.Email),
            new SqlParameter("@Img", student.Img),
            new SqlParameter("@CityId", student.CityId)
        };
        var result = db.Exec(connection, "spInsertNewStudent", sqlParam);
        db.StopConnection(connection);
         return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: You have to cast type object to your Student type like this (MyType) student

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# cast object to its datatype obj.GetType();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821151/c-sharp-cast-object-to-its-datatype-obj-gettype)

Comment: yes, thanks, u all opened my eyes for the cause, i was too fixed after missing reference, no need to down vote me for that, i'm a beginner and my question was clear and clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of student is `object`, or more formally `System.Object`. This type hasn't any property called `Name` or `Lname` etc. That's the problem. You should change the type to the class used to create the student object. For instance if you have created the Student object like below:

```
var student = new Student
{
    Name = "foo"
    // .....
}
```

You should change the signature of your method like below:

```
public bool InsertStudent(Student student)
```

Comment: You can still can use object, just cast it to Student before use

Comment: yep, should have used DAL.Models.Student as the type (thanks man)

Comment: @VinodSrivastav You are correct. This is can be done. However I don't see any reason to follow this way. Generally casting is bad practice, since it is like to argue that you are more smart thatn the compiler, whose one of it's jobs is this. Of course it is unavoidable in some cases and we should use it, but in this case I don't see any reason. For instance, let that you have a reference to this method that cannot be casted to a `Student` object. This would end throw an exception. By stating clearly that the type of object you should pass is Student, you avoid this from the beginning.

Comment: @Christos: That makes sense since the method itself is called "InsertStudent"

Answer (score 0):

Parameter 'student' has an 'Object' type. This is base type for all classes and structures. You should cast 'student' to your class type

```
public bool InsertStudent(object obj)
{
    var student = (Student)obj;
    ....
}
```

Or change 'student' parameter type

```
public bool InsertStudent(Student student)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Student class insted of object class

```
public bool InsertStudent(Student student)
{
    var db = DAL.Services.SqlServicesPool.HackService;
    using (var connection = db.StartConnection())
    {
        var sqlParam = new SqlParameter[]
      {
        new SqlParameter("@Name", student.Name),
        new SqlParameter("@Lname", student.Lname),
        new SqlParameter("@Phone", student.Phone),
        new SqlParameter("@Email", student.Email),
        new SqlParameter("@Img", student.Img),
        new SqlParameter("@CityId", student.CityId)
      };
      var result = db.Exec(connection, "spInsertNewStudent", sqlParam);
      db.StopConnection(connection);
      return result;
   };
}

public class Student
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Lname { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public byte []Img { get; set; }
   public string CityId { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public bool InsertStudent((Student)object student){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Christos commented, you need to use a Student object rather.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; } //Wasn't sure what type you use here
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass through a Student object as your parameter.

```
public bool InsertStudent(Student student)
{
    var db = DAL.Services.SqlServicesPool.HackService;
    using (var connection = db.StartConnection())
    {
        var sqlParam = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@Name", student.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Lname", student.Lname),
            new SqlParameter("@Phone", student.Phone),
            new SqlParameter("@Email", student.Email),
            new SqlParameter("@Img", student.Img),
            new SqlParameter("@CityId", student.CityId)
        };
        var result = db.Exec(connection, "spInsertNewStudent", sqlParam);
        db.StopConnection(connection);
        return result;
    };
}
```